# Phonegap online Android app release build is not installing into my phone?

Tags: android, cordova, publishing

Hi everyone i am facing a strange issue. 
When ever i try to build source code for android app online (https://build.phonegap.com/) with my keystore then app is not getting install into my android phone and it says "App not installed". But when i try to compile it without any keystore app is installing into my phone. I want a release android application for publishing. Am using phonegap 2.9.0. What is wrong with this?? I really need help from you guys am not expert of phonegap. Please help me out!

Comment: Did you include the config.xml File with your app code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating cordova to 3.5.0 solved my problem